# how to updated nested lists in rethinkdb using .net

Tags: .net, rethinkdb

I have 
class University which have list of students which have list of locations.
Do you have any ideas to I can update it using that driver.

in javascript it is straight forward

r.db("myDb").table("universities").get("id...").("students")("locations").update(..)

with c # not sure how I can do it.

Comment: Could you post a sample of what "students" and "locations" look like. Is location a list of objects or just a list of strings?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your query works in **JavaScript**. I don't think you can do an `.update()` immediately after `("students")("locations")`. I get an error, `Expected type SELECTION but found DATUM:`, in **JavaScript** when replacing the `locations` array with your query.

However, if you use [**this C# ReQL driver**](https://github.com/bchavez/RethinkDb.Driver) via [**NuGet**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RethinkDb.Driver), to replace the `locations` array in **C#**:

```
var result = r.db("myDb").table("universities")
              .get("id...")
              .update(new { students = new { locations = ...})
              .runResult(conn);
```

If it works in **JavaScript** it should also work with this **C#** driver.

Comment: When I run this statement, assuming students was an array and locations was an array, they both now become objects. So instead of append some value to the location collection I get locations replaced as a nested object under a students object

Comment: @cecilphillip Hey there, yeah, that's what I get too. I think here I didn't assume students was an array (I assume an object for sake of simplicity). It was only to demonstrate how to update/replace a nested array. I have an example in the repo I'll push later.